# Power of tangent is odd and positive- integration

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

So I am currently studying trig substitution and am curious about the process involved in finding an answer.

$$ \int \frac {\tan^{3}(x)}{\sqrt {\sec(x)}}  dx$$

$$=\int \sec(x)^{-1/2}{\tan} ^{3}(x)dx$$
At this point I struggle to understand why and how exactly we come about to our next step. 
$$ =\int (\sec x)^{-3/2}({\tan}^2x)(\sec x \tan x)dx$$
I understand that we must apply the process that follows if a power of the tangent is odd and positive which gives us the preceding step but the process from step to step seems really confusing right here. How exactly is secant raised to the negative one half changed to a negative three halfs?

Comment: $\sec^{-1/2}x = \sec^{-3/2}x \sec x$ by the addition of the powers.

Comment: wow what a boneheaded mistake on my part lol, thank you. @BennettGardiner

Answer (score 1):

Let $u =\sec x$ so that $du =\sec x \tan x $. Then we have 
$$
\int \frac{u^2-1}{u^{3/2}}\;du=\int u^{1/2}-u^{-3/2}\;du=\frac{6+2u^2}{3\sqrt{u}}+C
$$
Substituting what we started with, we have the solution
$$
\frac{6+2\sec^2x}{\sqrt{\sec x}}+C
$$